# How to generate a regExp using a String literal?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a regex in ES6,  with a String Literal, but my solution fails :

```
var prefix = 'Hello';

var re = /`${prefix}\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)`/;
//var re = /Hello\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/; // this works

var str = 'Hello John Smith';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: You can only use `${..}` in template literals. If you want to use a template literal, pass it to `new Regexp`.

Comment: why is this question being downvoted? It's fairly obvious what he's trying to achieve, and the solution is not trivial

Comment: @Phil this question is **not a duplicate**, the referenced question uses variables, here string literals are used

Comment: @colxi I don't really think that constitutes a difference. Also, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828436/283366) uses string literals

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `new RegExp`

```js
var prefix = 'Hello';
var reStr = `${prefix}\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)`;
var re = new RegExp(reStr,'g')

var str = 'Hello John Smith';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```